# How to communicate between two separate class?

Tags: c#

I have created the separate class called connection and I have returned the `SqlConnection` like this :

```
class connection
{
    public SqlConnection Functions()
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        Boolean flag = false;
        connetionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        return cnn;
    }

}
```

And I want to use the returned connection in another separate class but it seems error , I have coded as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using WindowsFormsApplication1.deepak;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection cnn ;

            connection c = new connection();
            cnn = new connection.Function();
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `connection` class(that I prefer `Connection` instead `connection`), should be accessible from outside, so I set its modifier to `public`:

```
public class Connection
{
   public SqlConnection Function()
   {
      var connetionString = /*your connection string*/
      return new SqlConnection(connetionString);
   }
}
```

Now, you can use it as following:

```
var conn = new Connection().Function(); //<--- you forgot the parentheses
try
{
   conn.Open();
   MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
   conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for `cnn = c.Functions();` instead of  `cnn = new connection.Function();`
I would also suggest to use [standard C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use a capital letter at the start of your class name and to give your method a name that would describe its purpose such as `GetConnection()`.